# React Warning.js - How to figure out where in the code the error is originating from?

Tags: reactjs

In React warning.js, it gives an error message indicating what the problem is, but the stack trace seems to be completely unrelated to the issue, like in the example below. Is there any way to get a line number or file which is causing the issue?

> Warning: Unknown DOM property for. Did you mean htmlFor?warning @ warning.js?8a56:45warnUnknownProperty @ DOMPropertyOperations.js?930e:68DOMPropertyOperations.createMarkupForProperty @ DOMPropertyOperations.js?930e:115ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createOpenTagMarkupAndPutListeners @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:548ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:478ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:37obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:241ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:591ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:479ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:37obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:241ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:591ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:479ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:37obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:241ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:591ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:479ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:37obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:241ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:591ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:479ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:37obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:241ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:591ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:479ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:37obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:225wrapper @ ReactPerf.js?ef93:66ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:37obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactMultiChild.Mixin._mountChildByNameAtIndex @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:474ReactMultiChild.Mixin._updateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:378ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:326ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:871ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:700ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:645ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:87obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactChildReconciler.updateChildren @ ReactChildReconciler.js?ff46:84ReactMultiChild.Mixin._reconcilerUpdateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:216ReactMultiChild.Mixin._updateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:351ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:326ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:871ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:700ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:645ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:87obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactChildReconciler.updateChildren @ ReactChildReconciler.js?ff46:84ReactMultiChild.Mixin._reconcilerUpdateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:216ReactMultiChild.Mixin._updateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:351ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:326ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:871ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:700ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:645ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:87obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactChildReconciler.updateChildren @ ReactChildReconciler.js?ff46:84ReactMultiChild.Mixin._reconcilerUpdateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:216ReactMultiChild.Mixin._updateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:351ReactMultiChild.Mixin.updateChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js?c87d:326ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._updateDOMChildren @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:871ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.updateComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:700ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.receiveComponent @ ReactDOMComponent.js?1302:645ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:87obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:562ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:544ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:473wrapper @ ReactPerf.js?ef93:66ReactCompositeComponentMixin.receiveComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:405ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:87obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:562ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:544ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:473wrapper @ ReactPerf.js?ef93:66ReactCompositeComponentMixin.receiveComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:405ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:87obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:562ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:544ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:473wrapper @ ReactPerf.js?ef93:66ReactCompositeComponentMixin.receiveComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:405ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:87obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:562ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:544ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:473wrapper @ ReactPerf.js?ef93:66ReactCompositeComponentMixin.receiveComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:405ReactReconciler.receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:87obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:562ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:544ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:473wrapper @ ReactPerf.js?ef93:66ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performUpdateIfNecessary @ ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:421ReactReconciler.performUpdateIfNecessary @ ReactReconciler.js?6bfa:102obj.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:8386runBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js?ce09:129Mixin.perform @ Transaction.js?6dff:136Mixin.perform @ Transaction.js?6dff:136assign.perform @ ReactUpdates.js?ce09:86flushBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js?ce09:147wrapper @ ReactPerf.js?ef93:66Mixin.closeAll @ Transaction.js?6dff:202Mixin.perform @ Transaction.js?6dff:149ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js?ef70:62batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js?ce09:94ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent @ ReactEventListener.js?2365:204

Comment: Not sure what the problem with the stack trace is (maybe missing source maps or something similar), but it seems like you used `for` in JSX instead of `htmlFor`. So a recursive search for `for=` should at least give the location of the issue and maybe hints why the stack trace is weird.

Comment: If the answer below helped you (even though I alreadz answered 1 1/2 year ago) I would kindly ask you to mark it as accepted answer. :)

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Thanks so much for trying to help. I don't remember what this issue is anymore, but I totally would have selected it if it was haha.

Comment: @Dobler Thanks for your response. I am pretty sure it was this error. It is typical that developers mistakenly use `for` instead of `htmlFor` in JSX. It was also @inyono's guess. ;)

Comment: @MarkusWeninger thanks again for trying to help, but that was not the issue. The question that I was trying to ask (I should clean up the question) at the time was how to stack trace Javascript in the client better.

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: Unknown DOM property for. Did you mean htmlFor?

The very first line tells you everything you need to know: Somewhere in your JSX file you are using `for`, but in JSX you have to use `htmlFor` instead.

Example:

```
<div>
  <label htmlFor="name">Enter your name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
</div>
```